# Unexpected unindent python to execute an sql query

Tags: python

I have this python code to execute an sql file:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='skynetadmin',
                     password='Skynetadmin1',
                     host='silmysskytest01.sing.micron.com',
                     database='skynet_msa')
cursor =cnx.cursor()

def executeScriptsFromFile(filename):
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

for command in sqlCommands:
    try:
        if command.strip() != '':
            cursor.execute(command)


executeScriptsFromFile('C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428\Query_for_testingintern.sql')
cnx.commit()
```

Hwv, I have this error:

```
executeScriptsFromFile('C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428')
^ unexpected unindent
```

I tried moving ard with the indents but it gives me no solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your try has no except.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector
def executeScriptsFromFile(Query_for_testingintern):
    fd = open(Query_for_testingintern, 'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

    for command in sqlCommands:
        try:
            if command.strip() != '':
                cursor.execute(command)
                
        except:
            pass
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='skynetadmin',password='Skynetadmin1',host='silmysskytest01.sing.micron.com',database='skynet_msa')
cursor =cnx.cursor()

executeScriptsFromFile("C:\\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428")
cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Also try using some IDE like vscode

Comment: your fir loop was out of indentation

Comment: it still gives me the same error

Comment: fixed.. try now

Comment: thank you but now they said: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\gsumarlin\\Documents\\dumps\\Dump20220428'

Comment: oops i just edited the qn. apparently the file directory is: 'C:\\Users\\gsumarlin\\Documents\\dumps\\Dump20220428\\Query_for_testingintern.sql' but still gives me no such file or directory

Answer (score -1):

Do you use Notepad++ or something like that?

You can simply open the file there and select all (Ctrl + A)
Then click on "Edit" -> Non printable characters -> Convert Tabs to Spaces