# No file or directory found despite having the file in python to execute an sql file

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

In relation to this question: [Unexpected unindent python to execute an sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880582/unexpected-unindent-python-to-execute-an-sql-query)

This is my python script:

```
import mysql.connector
def executeScriptsFromFile(filename):
    fd = open(filename,'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

    for command in sqlCommands:
        try:
            if command.strip() != '':
                cursor.execute(command)
            
        except:
            pass
        
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='skynetadmin',password='Skynetadmin1',host='silmysskytest01.sing.micron.com',database='skynet_msa')
cursor =cnx.cursor()


executeScriptsFromFile(r'C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428\Query_for_testingintern.sql')
cnx.commit()
```

I have an issue like this under the open function:

```
fd = open(filename,'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\gsumarlin\\Documents\\dumps\\Dump20220428\\Query_for_testingintern.sql'
```

I tried with other files but they all give me the same error. Does anyone know why?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

EDITED:

output from os.listdir:

```
os.listdir(r'C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428\Query_for_testingintern.sql')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\gsumarlin\\Documents\\dumps\\Dump20220428\\Query_for_testingintern.sql'
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the path correct (like right spelling and all that)?

Comment: yes. it is absolutely correct which is why i am very confused

Comment: Please show a partial listing of ```dir c:\\Users\\gsumarlin\\Documents\\dumps\\Dump20220428```

Comment: i used os.listdir but it also shows no such file or directory

Comment: Please provide output from suggestion by @ewong.
Also, just to be sure, try to place the sql file in the same location as the script is running and see if it will find it without the whole directory.
you can also ```from pathlib import Path``` then ```Path(r'C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428\Query_for_testingintern.sql')```

Comment: You do a ```os.listdir(r'C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428')```

Comment: @1extralimeur suggestion works! thank you

Comment: listdir() argument is a directory not a file